# how to write to a new cell in python using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I wrote code which opens an excel file and iterates through each row and passes the value to another function.

```
import openpyxl
wb = load_workbook(filename='C:\Users\xxxxx')
for ws in wb.worksheets:
    for row in ws.rows:
        print row
        x1=ucr(row[0].value)
        row[1].value=x1  #  i am having error at this point
```

I am getting the following error when I tried to run the file.

```
TypeError: IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Can I write the returned value `x1` to the `row[1]` column. Is it possible to write to excel (i.e using `row[1]`) instead of accessing single cells like `ws.['c1']=x1`

Comment: Your code does not reflect what you say want to do.

Answer (score 71):

Try this:

```
import openpyxl
wb = load_workbook(filename='xxxx.xlsx')
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
ws['A1'] = 1
ws.cell(row=2, column=2).value = 2
```

This will set Cells A1 and B2 to 1 and 2 respectively (two different ways of setting cell values in a worksheet).

The second method (specifying row and column) is most useful for your situation:

```
import openpyxl
wb = load_workbook(filename='xxxxx.xlsx')
for ws in wb.worksheets:
    for index, row in enumerate(ws.rows, start=1):
        print row
        x1 = ucr(row[0].value)
        ws.cell(row=index, column=2).value = x1
```

Comment: there are 150 rows, it will be tough to access each cell and write the data.    like ws['a1']=x1,ws['a2']='' . i wish to have general solution.Thanks for the help

Comment: So use the second form I gave: ws.cell(row=X, column=Y).value = V

Comment: I have updated my answer to include how you might use that method in your particular situation.

Comment: Note that the changes will not be reflected in the Excel file unless you save the file.  `wb.save(fileName)`

Comment: In openpyxl 3.0.7 the method using `ws.cell(row, column)/ws.cell(coordinate)` doesn't work any more. `ws["A1"]` works as expected.

Comment: @Cecilya - I checked the documentation, and it no longer mentions the "coordinate" kwarg, so I think you're right about method 3 not working anymore. I just tested all of these again on openpyxl 3.0.9, though, and the second one does still work for me there. And according to the documentation and my testing, apparently `ws.cell(row=4, column=4, value=4)` also works now, however I think the second method in my answer is clearer, so I am going to leave it out. I am updating my answer to reflect the third method not working anymore.