# how to match the column value from one file to another using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to insert data from excel then match it to another excel data using vc_no column and Type (Secondary, Primary) as my key to put the data to respective column. here's an example:

## First excel file

```
                 secondary pairs         primary pair       
vc_no   stat     vc_no1 c_result1        vc_no2 c_result2       

472594  NULL
264781  NULL
974621  NULL
231412  NULL
314283  NULL
NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL
```

What I wanted to do is get the value of The `sourcefile` and insert it to their respective columns based on their `block type` and `vc_no`.

## Sourcefile

```
Block Type  vc_no   c_result
Primary     n/a     not match
Primary     n/a     match
Primary     472594  match
Primary     974621  match
Primary     231412  not match
Secondary   314283  match   
Secondary   264781  match
Secondary   974621  match
```

## What I want to achieve

```
                  secondary-pairs        primary-pairs      
vc_no   stat      vc_no1    c_result1    vc_no2     c_result2           
472594  NULL      NULL      NULL         472594     match
264781  NULL      264781    match
974621  NULL                             974621     match
231412  NULL                             231412     not match   
314283  NULL      314283    match
                                         n/a        not match
NULL    NULL                             n/a        match
NULL    NULL                             n/a        not match
```

I tried matching my data thru vc_no with isin() by pandas and fetching the block type value by using .str.contains() and  put them to their columns by using .columns[] and works fine.

## the problem

I need to get the `vc_no` its `block type` and its `comp_res` then match it with existing `vc_no, block type and comp_res` from another data-frame. but what I am getting is just the value of `vc_no` to the specified match column. `note:I am writing it to a new file.`

## Here's my Code

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.read_excel("firstexcelfile.xlsx")
df_2 = pd.read_excel("sourcefile.xlsx", "v0.02")


vc_Secondary = df_1.columns[16]
adsl_old = df_1.columns[36]

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(df_1)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(df_2)

Primary = df_2['Block Type'].str.contains('Primary')
Secondary = df_2['Block Type'].str.contains('Secondary')


df_2[Primary].to_excel("Primary.xlsx")
df_2[Secondary].to_excel("Secondary.xlsx")

File = pd.read_excel("firstexcelfile.xlsx")
secFile = pd.read_excel("Primary.xlsx")

secID = secFile.columns[13]
ads = File.columns[39]

df_1 = df_1[df_1['vc_no'].isin(secFile[secID])]
df_1[vc_Secondary] = df_1['vc_no']

df_1[ads] = df_2[['Block Name', 'Pair']].apply(lambda x: '/'.join(x.astype(str)), axis=1)
df_1 = df_1[df_1['vc_no'].isin(File[adsl])]
df_1[ads_old] = df_1['ads']

df_1.to_excel('util_CAB_sample.xlsx')
```

Comment: Recommend you review the "Comparison with SQL" section of [pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_sql.html) . Scroll down to the "Join" section. This might make life easier for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several methods are possible, here one example if I understand well your question. I created my input with only necessary columns in `df_first` and `df_source` but if you get other columns when you read excel, no problem normally.

```
import pandas as pd
# Create both DF with used data
df_first = pd.DataFrame({'vc_no':[472594, 264781, 974621, 231412, 314283]})
df_source = pd.DataFrame({'Block Type': ['Primary','Primary','Primary', 'Secondary', 'Secondary', 'Secondary'],
                          'vc_no':[472594, 974621, 231412, 314283, 264781, 974621],
                          'c_result':['match','match','not match','match','match','match']})

# Select data you want to add to df_first from df_source where Block Type = Primary
df_prim = df_source[['vc_no','c_result']][(df_source['Block Type'] == 'Primary')]
# Then use apply() to create the two column for Block Type = primary
df_first[['c_result_primary','vc_no_primary']] = df_first['vc_no'].apply(lambda x: df_prim[df_prim['vc_no'] == x].iloc[0] if x in list(df_prim['vc_no']) else pd.Series())
#Same for Block Type = secondary
df_sec = df_source[['vc_no','c_result']][(df_source['Block Type'] == 'Secondary')]
df_first[['c_result_secondary','vc_no_secondary']] = df_first['vc_no'].apply(lambda x: df_sec[df_sec['vc_no'] == x].iloc[0] if x in list(df_sec['vc_no']) else pd.Series())
# Fill nan with empty string
df_first = df_first.fillna('')
```

The results is like

```
    vc_no c_result_primary vc_no_primary c_result_secondary vc_no_secondary
0  472594            match        472594                                   
1  264781                                             match          264781
2  974621            match        974621              match          974621
3  231412        not match        231412                                   
4  314283                                             match          314283
```

Comment: Hello Ben, Thank you. this is really helpful. I am now working on how I'll get the values and put it to a specific column in excel. from your code, I am trying to assign a column but can't put it into work. I got the column c_result_primary and vc_no_primary value then say I have `column[37]` for `vc_no_primary` and `column[40]` for `c_result_primary`. how will I write it to the outputfile? sorry, newb question I'm really new to programming.

Comment: @kenneth_V To be sure, you want just to write the two columns into an Excel file already existing or you have a dataframe with more than 40 columns and want to assign the value to the 37th and 40th column?

Comment: I have an existing excel file with more than 40 columns and I want to write the values into specific columns instead of creating new.

Comment: I know two choices (probably more exist): load your existing Excel file into a pandas DF , change the two columns you want in your DF and rewrite the DF into the same Excel file (might be long depending on the amount of data to load-write) or use the library `openpyxl`, check the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31395058/how-to-write-to-a-new-cell-in-python-using-openpyxl?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)  with a loop on the column of df_first.