# How to Assign Value From a Variable to an Excel Cell with Python

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, automation, worksheet

I want to assign the value of the variable game_type to excel cell but i am unable to do so:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Table1.xlsx')
Card13 = wb.active
print Card13
class private_table():
    def __init__(self, game):
        if game == 13:
            game_type = game
            Card13['A2'] = game_type
            wb.save('Table1.xlsx')
            print(game_type)
        elif game == '21':
            game_type = int(game)
            print(game_type)
        elif game == '27':
            game_type = int(game)
            print(game_type)
        else:
            print("Enter correct game type")
    def noc(self, cards):
        if cards == 13:
            game_type = Card13['A2'].value
            if game_type == '13':
                num_of_cards = cards
                print num_of_cards
                return num_of_cards
            else:
                print ("Please select the correct number of cards")
                return("Please select the correct number of cards")
        elif cards == '21':
            game_type = Card13['B1'].value
            if game_type == '21':
                num_of_cards = cards
                print num_of_cards
                return num_of_cards
            else:
                print ("Please select the correct number of cards")
                return("Please select the correct number of cards")
        elif cards == '27':
            game_type = Card13['B1'].value
            if game_type == '27':
                num_of_cards = cards
                print num_of_cards
                return num_of_cards
            else:
                print ("Please select the correct number of cards")
                return("Please select the correct number of cards")
```

Comment: What isn't working with your code above? And did you see this [how to write to a new cell in python using openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31395058/how-to-write-to-a-new-cell-in-python-using-openpyxl) ?

Comment: I want to write the value of the variable 'game_type' to the cell Card13['A2'], which is not working for me.

Comment: What are you expecting from this line - `print Card13`?

Comment: @Vityata i wanted to see which is the active sheet that has been selected.

Comment: @AbhijitD - I see. So what are you expecting to have printed? Name, variable name or reference? Or you got an error on that line?

Comment: @Vityata i was expecting a name reference of the sheet and no i did not get any error on that line.

Comment: @AbhijitD - What is "name reference"? A name like "Sheet1" or an address in the memory, something like `0x23af4234`?

Comment: @Vityata just a name like "Sheet1".

Comment: @AbhijitD - and did you get it? You seem to be working with `python 2.X`, I cannot replicate...

Comment: @Vityata yes i got it and yes i am working with python 2.7

Comment: In your code, how are you initializing the class `private_table`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the solution that helped me insert the value of a variable in a excel sheet.

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Table1.xlsx')
Card13 = wb.active
print Card13
class private_table():
    def __init__(self, game):
        if game == 13:
            game_type = game
            Card13['B1'] = game_type
            wb.save('Table1.xlsx')
            print(game_type)
        elif game == 21:
            game_type = (game)
            Card13['B1'] = game_type
            wb.save('Table1.xlsx')
            print(game_type)
        elif game == 27:
            game_type = (game)
            wb.save('Table1.xlsx')
            Card13['B1'] = game_type
            print(game_type)
        else:
            print("Enter correct game type")
```

Answer (score 2):

[From the documentation of openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), this is how you write in Excel:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()

# grab the active worksheet
ws = wb.active

# Data can be assigned directly to cells
ws['A1'] = 42

# Rows can also be appended
ws.append([1, 2, 3])

# Python types will automatically be converted
import datetime
ws['A2'] = datetime.datetime.now()

# Save the file
wb.save("sample.xlsx")
```

---

If you decide to use [xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/), this is some working sample, working for Python 3. For Python 2, remove the parenthesis from the `print ()` to look like this - `print wks2.name`.

```
import xlsxwriter
from xlsxwriter.utility import xl_rowcol_to_cell

wbk = xlsxwriter.Workbook('testing.xlsx')
wks = wbk.add_worksheet()
wks.write('A1', 'Hello world')
print (wks.name)
wks2 = wbk.add_worksheet()
print (wks2.name)

i = -1

for x in range(1, 1000, 11):
    i+=1
    cella = xl_rowcol_to_cell(i, 0) #0,0 is A1!
    cellb = xl_rowcol_to_cell(i, 1)
    cellc = xl_rowcol_to_cell(i, 2)
    print (cella)
    wks2.write(cella,x)
    wks2.write(cellb,x*3)
    wks2.write(cellc,x*4.5)
wbk.close()
```

You just need to have a workbook named `testing.xlsx` in the same directory with Python. Then you get this on the first sheet:

[image]

and this on the added sheet:

[image]

And this is what you get if you run the code with Python:

[image]

The name of the worksheets come from `print(wks.name)` and `print(wks2.name)`.