# How to copy and paste text file into a specified Excel TAB using Python?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have 5 excel tabs in a certain sheet that I need to copy and paste text files into. I know how to a certain cell of a normal excel sheet with one tab. But I have no idea how to copy and paste each text file to the correct tab as there are formulas in each one.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi alanireland, welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried so far? Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31395058/how-to-write-to-a-new-cell-in-python-using-openpyxl ?

Answer (score -1):

you can achive using python panda

```
import pandas as pd

# Create some Pandas dataframes from some data.
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [11, 12, 13, 14]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [21, 22, 23, 24]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [31, 32, 33, 34]})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_multiple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Write each dataframe to a different worksheet.
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet2')
df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet3')

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

Comment: What if he has graphics in his file that he doesn't want to lose?